# Connect downloaded git repository to remote

Tags: git, gitlab, git-clone

I was having issues cloning a large git repository, so I had to download it manually.

Is there a way to connect this downloaded folder (which doesn't have a `.git`) to remote?

(note: `git clone` is still not an option, even after changing timeout configs)

Answer (score 0):

No, if you downloaded a snapshot of the repository, you're missing the history information necessary to match the remote.

You can create a local git repository on top of it to keep track of your own changes, but you'll never be able to push them back upstream to the original repository.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to connect this downloaded folder (which doesn't have a .git) to remote?

I think we could do it. We could try the following steps:

1. In folder which contains source code, we create an empty git repository using `git init` with default branch `master`.
2. We add remote repository that we need using `git remote add name_repo link_repo`.
3. We download objects and refs from remote repository `git fetch --all`. Now, we could view commit logs using `git log --all`.
4. We rollback default branch of remote repository using `git reset --hard name_repo/master`.

[image]

Comment: Your suggestion still requires a `git fetch --all`. Wouldn't this be just as slow as `git clone`?
That being said, this *might* have just worked for me, or maybe it worked because of a temporary boost in wideband..?